Why is 'request.auth' always equal to 'null' in the rule settings of my Firebase project although a user is logged in?
These are my security rules in firebase firestore:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

This is my custom hook to listen on user authentication and making a data fetch based on this authentication:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "./config";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { getUserData } from "../actions/userActions";

function useAuth() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(undefined);
  const [uid, setUid] = useState<any>(undefined);
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState<any>(undefined);
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState<any>(undefined);
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState<any>(undefined);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<any>(undefined);
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState<any>(undefined);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState<any>(undefined);
  const [role, setRole] = useState<any>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async (user: any) => {
      let userData = await getUserData(user.uid);
      if (userData) {
        setUid(userData.uid);
        setFirstName(userData.firstName);
        setLastName(userData.lastName);
        setDisplayName(userData.displayName);
        setEmail(userData.email);
        setPhone(userData.phone);
        setAddress(userData.address);
        setRole(userData.role);
      }
    };

    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        fetchUserData(user);
      } else {
        setUser(undefined);
        setUid(undefined);
        setFirstName(undefined);
        setLastName(undefined);
        setDisplayName(undefined);
        setEmail(undefined);
        setPhone(undefined);
        setAddress(undefined);
        setRole(undefined);
      }
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  });

  return {
    user,
    uid,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    displayName,
    email,
    phone,
    address,
    role,
  };
}

export default useAuth;


And this is the 'getUserData' function:
export const getUserData = async (uid: string) => {
  try {
    const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(firestore, "users", uid));
    if (snapshot) return snapshot.data();
    else return undefined;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error at 'getUserData': " + e);
    return undefined;
  }
};

Then on client side I just do:
const {user} = useAuth()
and use the user object in a tag:
<p>{user.uid}</p>
Without setting the security rules the authentication and data fetching is working fine but as soon as I set the rules (like in the example above) I get the error:
FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
Although I think there are no database fetches before the user is logged in completely.
If I change the rules to be:
allow read, write: if true;
or
allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
Everything works as expected.
Why does the 'request.auth' not have the right value when a user is logged in?

changing the rules to be 'request.auth.uid'
clearing cache
use the rules playground to see if the rules are correct for what I want
adding more conditions into the code to make sure no fetch is made before user is logged in


What is the code of getUserData()?

Sorry I forgot that, I added it to my question.

Note that checking that the DocumentSnapshot (i.e. the snapshot object) is not empty with if (snapshot) will always return true. You need to use if (snapshot.exists()).

It was already pointed out by an other user and it doen't change anything with my main problem. Thank you, anyways!

I am the other user ;-) I just deleted my answer and transformed it in a comment since it didn't answer your problem.

Could you also include the code snippet for user authentication? what sign-in provider are you using?
